# Check if "setFullScreenIntent" leads to a launch of the application or to the display of a notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification

I get a firebase notification and create a NotificationCompat.Builder with the "setFullScreenIntent" option. This leads to different behaviours on different systems or different device status.
Sometimes the app launches directly, sometimes a notification is displayed.

I have to surpress a ringtone if the user clicked on the notification but play it when the app starts directly.

How do I get to know which one happened when my activity starts?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to:
improve text arragement, improve code formatting


.

See [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my English.

You can do cancel the Notification in `activity#onCreate` or other lifecycle where you want

Comment: The notification is cancelled automatically when the application starts. But I don't know if it was started by clicking the application or automatically from the system. I need to know that I can start a ringtone or not.